Is The Knowledge of Zero Qualitatively Different From The Knowledge of Infinity?
I look at Zero and Infinity, Quantitatively, one is Nothing vs other Everything.
For some reason I find Zero more intuitive than Infinity. Just wanted to know if there is some  difference between these two Knowledge, such that I can find a solution to whatever I am lacking in and help me quickly understand Infinity...

It is not usual to identify "infinity" with "everything".  Everything might or might not be infinite.  Any particular infinity might or might not include everything.

I'm fond of a grammatical concept from Finnish: in many cases (such as their verb for "to love') the object must be a participle. It cannot be in the nomnative case becasue only God can entirely love anyone. I embrace the concepts of zero and infinity in the same way. I can easily (as a mere mortal) understand the fact that I don't have something (zero), but only God can really understand what it means to have everything (infinity). I like to think I can dream big... but dreaming of an infinite amount of gold is a bit beyond me. Not having any gold... not so hard.

Just to throw in some lateral interference - "The IEEE 754 standard for floating-point arithmetic (presently used by most computers and programming languages that support floating-point numbers) requires both +0 and −0. Real arithmetic with signed zeros can be considered a variant of the extended real number line such that 1/−0 = −∞ and 1/+0 = +∞; division is undefined only for ±0/±0 and ±∞/±∞. "

@Miss_Understands It depends on at what level or how you look at this question. If you haven't faced this question on your own it might seem vague, but if you have spent enough time on it but failed, then you would know that it is very focussed. 0 and Infinity are just two extreme contrasting examples of concepts. If you find grasping these two concepts difficult then it's natural to ask, whether there is some difference in the way these two are understood. If I were to apply the same logic to your comment, I can very easily say the EXACT same thing about your comment.

@CraigHicks Yes, I know about negative zero. I did systems programming in assembler on a mainframe that used negative 0. It makes logical compliment operations very quick. And yes, someone actually built a computer that allows positive and negative Infinity. So what? That's just mapping bits to values.

@AshishShukla >  If I were to apply the same logic to your comment, I can very easily say the EXACT same thing about your comment. === You can say what about my comment? That is both zero and infinite? . I don't understand.

@miss_understands That it is Vague and Less-Well Defined...

@AshishShukla You don't think the OP question is vague and ill-defined?

@Miss_Understands nope, I don't think it's ill defined, see it is not about the Concept of Zero or Infinity, it's about the "Knowledge of Concept". Why one is comparatively easier to understand while other isn't. A simple thing to do is to RePhrase the question to see whether it can be made more crisp while retaining the original thought. Can you please rephrase the Question for me. It'll immensly help me.

How about the "empty set" vs "the set of all sets".

@CraigHicks since I am not well versed with sets, for me your simili is not very intuitive. To me 0 and Infinity make more sense...

Form an historical point of view, there is a difference.
The zero number is a quite peculiar concept.
If originally humans introduced counting numbers to count objects into bags, flocks,armies... the idea to have a "number" to count no object at all can sound strange. But it was quite useful for e.g. accounting.
Relevant: Abraham Seidenberg's research on the origins of mathematics, e.g. The Ritual Origin of Counting (1962).
The "discovery" of the zero numeral was indeed crucial for the development of Positional notation.
Quite diffrent is the history of Infinity: the concept has been discussed by many philosophers (see e.g. Aristotle), while the idea to stretch the concept of number to count infinities is a quite modern one.
Regarding nothing, see Nothingness: from a philosophical point of view, it can be considered quite different from the number zero.

I'd have thought that knowing that there were nothing things in  a bag would be quite useful :-).

@RussellMcMahon I see your :-) Still, what I think this answer already says but could be made even clearer; there was of course words for denoting empty and lack of, just no number to denote it since it fx can seem strange to have a number of apples when you have no apples. We still use words rather than zero in day to day speech. Most people would say "I don't have any apples", rather than "I have 0 apples" unless in the context of accounting or a math puzzle or some such.

When I said Zero, I actually meant Nothing, which to me looks like Zero, Philosophically. Zero to me feels like quantified nothing as if someone assigned some value to Nothing. Thanks for the answer...

The mathematical number 0 is quite intuitive it's 1 less than 1, sits between the positive and the negative numbers, it's the neutral element of addition. In other words it actually quite neatly fits.
While infinity is more of a concept than a particular number. Like you don't even calculate with "infinity" as a number or symbol, if you do make math with it you usually express it as the limit of something going to infinity and leave it open where that stops (or that it doesn't and that that's the point).
Their combination also makes things quite weird because if you for example subdivide something into 1/x parts and let x go to 0 the number of parts goes to infinity. So close to infinity and close to 0 is 1, but also any other number if you want to and actual 0 times actual infinity should be...
That despite it's usefulness in accounting the actual idea of 0, bothered people quite a bit and if you ask people to imagine "nothing", then this "horror vacui" actually bothered quite some people. Even what we call vacuum today is still plenty filled and if you bring it in contact with "non-vacuum" there's a physical force that equilibrates pressure, so even the absence of physical objects isn't really the absence of physics, so is it actually "pure nothing" or just yet another approximation that isn't actually 0?

I can give you a half-dozen ways to calculate using infinity as a number off the top of my head, as should anyone with a half-decent undergraduate education in mathematics.  So I'm not sure your infinity argument holds water.  Ordinals, Cardinals, non-standard analysis using infinitesimals and their inverses, arguably in the p-adics, projective geometry... ok, only 5 off the top of my head.

@Yakk Not saying the concept isn't used in math, but your examples really stress what you'd colloquially see as "calculations" or "numbers". https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/36289/is-infinity-a-number#36298 . Like in your cases you still don't treat it as a fixed value but more as a concept or placeholder for an idea, like the size of a set or "the next element" or an upper undefined large or small boundary and so on.

So the way I understand it is like this due to an experiene in Life. There is a Zero, I've been there, it's not a Good Place to be. So the Feeling OF Nothing hence Zero is something that I have experienced so when you say "pure nothing" where even observer isn't present, is kinda intuitive to me, but this Infinity is a different. When I think about it, it becomes so big in my mind that it kinda collapses into Zero meaning, if this is EVERYTHING there is then there is NOTHING ELSE....

@AshishShukla The feeling of nothing is still a feeling and thus still a something. Also infinity doesn't need to mean everything, for example the future is likely to be infinite but it doesn't include the past, so it's not everything just something infinitely large.

@haxor789 I know that we can have infinity "within" some context, like future, or numbers, I am thinking more like infinity that encompasses everything, ABSOLUTELY EVERYTHING, space and time(Dr. Who fan here). It's like there is nothing else, not even the observer, then isn't that's what the Definition of Absolute Nothing as I read in some answer in SE that Absolute Nothingness is when There isn't even an Observer...

@haxor789 Hey was thinking about my comment and from our point of view; The Observer, in both the cases, ceases to exist as Independent Entity, in case of Zero, it doesn't exist AT ALL and in case of INFINITY, it becomes part of it. So that means, for the observer, Zero is UNTHINKABLE while Infinity cannot be seen from Outside. Just thinking Aloud Here.

@AshishShukla If you have no observer, then how do you know there isn't something, but if there is an observer, then there definitely is something. Also what is absolute nothing if you can't compare it to anything and can't see it how can you make sense of it? I like the idea of Zero being out of reach for the observer and universal being the observer as part of the observed. Though that's more than infinite which could also be a localized singularity that can be seen from the out and inside. Though rarely at once.

In mathematics “zero” and “infinity” are two totally different concepts.

Zero is a number from number theory, the neutral element of
addition. While infinity is the type of non-finite cardinal
numbers. "Cardinal number" is a term from Cantor’s set theory
characterizing the size of a set. Finite cardinal numbers are
just the natural numbers 0,1,2,3,…
It is quite common to have a better intuition of zero than of
infinity. It was Cantor who in the 19th century on the base of a
precise definition developed the theory of infinite cardinals.


I would actually think that infinity and zero are intimately linked concepts; they are linked by all relations which are inversely proportional. A see-saw with one ever shorter arm, a circuit whose resistance approaches zero, a mass which becomes ever lighter accelerated by a constant force. In all such examples, infinity emerges as the inverse of zero.

@Peter - ReinstateMonica Possibly. But there is only one number zero, but many - even infinitely many - different cardinals infinity.

There are a lot more infinities than Cardinals in mathematics.  Ordinals, non-standard analysis, use in limits, use in projective geometry for 4.

@Yakk Infinities in projective geometry result from the closure of affine spaces. The cardinality of an affine variety and its projective closure over R or C is the same, namely the cardinality of the underlying fields R oder C. - Each ordinal has an underlying cardinal, so you don't get more cardinals by considering ordinals. - I don't think that limits introduce new cardinals. - Concerning non-standard analysis I don't see why you will get more cardinals from non-standard analysis; please tell me why.

@JoWehler "More" as in "different, disjoint" not in "of a larger count".  Someone says "there are 5 apples"; if there is actually 1 apple and 2 oranges, there is "more" than what they said, even though 3 things is less than 5 things.  You can identify the oranges with apples, but they aren't the apples, so they aren't covered by "there are 5 apples".  There are more infinities in mathematics than just the Cardinals, because while Ordinals can be identified with Cardinals, they aren't Cardinals.

Zero knowledge and infinite knowledge are qualitatively very different, but both lie within certain conceptual boundaries that represent finality and absoluteness. This difference between absolute lack on the one hand and absolute perfection on the other hand.
